# Restricting loadings in Principal Component Analysis (PCA) to be just positive

Tags: r, pca

I can perform a PCA:

```
## (Simple) Robust PCA:
## Classical:
(pc.cl  <- princomp(stackloss))
## Robust:
(pc.rob <- princomp(stackloss, covmat = MASS::cov.rob(stackloss)))

loadings(pc.cl)
loadings(pc.rob)
```

But how can I add a constraint so that the loadings are just positive, with no negative values?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Maybe your searching for "Non-Negative Matrix Factorization".

Comment: Thanks very much for your advice.